# Soundcloud follow button does not line up with addthis follow buttons

Tags: alignment, soundcloud, addthis

I'm having an issue with a custom soundcloud button that I want to add to my addthis follow buttons.  Unfortunately, addthis does not natively support soundcloud follow so I am trying to manually insert it into the addthis toolbox.

The problem I am experiencing is that the soundcloud button does not line up correctly at the end of the other follow buttons.  The addthis help site says that it should be possible to just add a custom button to their toolbox.  The image I am using is the same size as the addthis auto-generated buttons.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is what it looks like:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ZCXj.jpg

Here is my code:

```
<div id="right-side-social">
<h3 style="padding: 10px 0px 10px 3px;">Follow Us!</h3>
<div class="addthis_toolbox addthis_32x32_style addthis_default_style">
<a class="addthis_button_facebook_follow" addthis:userid="xxxx"></a>
<a class="addthis_button_twitter_follow" addthis:userid="xxxx"></a>
<a class="addthis_button_youtube_follow" addthis:userid="xxxx"></a>
<a href="http://soundcloud.com/xxxx"><img border="0" src="http://www.xxxx.com/images/indexpics/soundcloud.jpg" alt="follow xxxx on soundcloud" width="32" height="32"></a>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript"src="http://s7.addthis.com/js/250/addthis_widget.js#pubid=xxxx"></script>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the Soundcloud button isn't aligning correctly, you can apply an inline style to move it up and to the left, so something like:

```
<a href="http://soundcloud.com/xxxx"><img border="0" src="http://www.xxxx.com/images/indexpics/soundcloud.jpg" alt="follow xxxx on soundcloud" width="32" height="32" style="margin-top:-15px;margin-left:-10px;"></a>
```

You will need to play with the margin-top and margin-left numbers to get them to align correctly.

Answer (score -1):

You can see how this solution looks [here](http://analogsheep.com/).

- Use SoundCloud follow widget found [here](https://soundcloud.com/pages/embed).
- Enclose the SoundCloud iframe with an AddThis class:

  ```
  <a class="addthis_button_facebook_follow">SOUNDCLOUD IFRAME GOES HERE</a>
  ```

  So it becomes:

  ```
  <a class="addthis_button_facebook_follow"><iframe allowtransparency="true" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" src="https://w.soundcloud.com/icon/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fsoundcloud.com%2Fanalogsheep&color=orange_white&size=32" style="width: 32px; height: 32px;"></iframe></a>
  ```
- Put this line next to other AddThis widgets.

  ```
  <div  style="position:fixed; margin: 85px 0 0 773px; z-index: 10000; width: 250px;">
      <div class="addthis_toolbox addthis_32x32_style addthis_default_style" style="margin: 0px 0 0 80px;">
          <a class="addthis_button_facebook_follow"><iframe allowtransparency="true" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" src="https://w.soundcloud.com/icon/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fsoundcloud.com%2Fanalogsheep&color=orange_white&size=32" style="width: 32px; height: 32px;"></iframe></a>
          <a class="addthis_button_twitter_follow" addthis:userid="theanalogsheep"></a>
          <a class="addthis_button_tumblr_follow" addthis:userid="analogsheep"></a>
          <a class="addthis_button_pinterest_follow" addthis:userid="analogsheep"></a>
      </div>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="//s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=YOUR ADDTHIS PUBLIC ID GOES HERE"></script>
  <div>
  ```

  **IMPORTANT:** This is my actual code working in [my site](http://analogsheep.com/). **Don't forget to change your AddThis ID at the end of the code!!!**